# Complex Limit with exponential

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have no clue where to start with this. Any hints?

limit (as n goes to infinity) of   $$e^{\frac{\pi((n^2+i)}{(in^2+1))}}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\dfrac{n^2+i}{in^2+1}\to\dfrac1i$.

So we get $e^{-\pi i}=-1$, by continuity of $e^z$.

Comment: why does (pi*1/i) equal (-pi*i) ?

Comment: Because $1/i=-i$.

Comment: oh duh! Thank you for your help chris!